# Combine v-on with VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Hello if I execute my code and press the up or down key, the "script_elastic" function will launch this when I don't want it to

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Saisir une adresse" class="search" autocomplete="off"
       @keydown.down="down"
       @keydown.up="up"
       @keydown.enter="enter"
       @keydown="search_elastic($event.target.value, $event)">
```

The stop Modifiers work only with child

Comment: Those modifiers are only for simple bindings: if you want to perform advanced logic (like stopping event propagation with a certain keycode), then you have to do it inside `search_elastic` method itself.

Answer (score 0):

As [terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry) commented, these modifiers are for simple bindins. 
Quick implementation of what you want to achieve, you can find [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-spfrq).

Comment: Thank you for your implementation I wanted to know if it is possible to do this with binding only

Comment: @overedge If I understanding what you are saying, then yes you can. You can check the keyCode inside the `search_elastic` function. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-e7zph)